# How to cast React children to typed array

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a reusable Table component.  My Table component should only have children of type TableColumn (another class component).  In my Table component's render() method, I want to access the children as a `TableColumn[]` object, but I'm having trouble casting the children to a typed array.

I'm trying the following:

```
const columns = React.Children.map(children, child => {
  return child as TableColumn;
});
```

I get the following error, though:

> Type 'ReactChild' cannot be converted to type 'TableColumn'.   Type
>   'ReactElement' is not comparable to type 'TableColumn'.
>       Property 'render' is missing in type 'ReactElement'.

How can I convert my Table's children opaque data structure into a typed array?